# Xamarin iOS - Background image does not fill page on iOS Tablets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an image that I use to fill the background on my log on page.

Android Phone - works OK

Android Tablet - works OK

iOS Phone - works OK

iOS Tablet - Does not extend all the way across (see image - dark green area to the right)

Code is simply:

```
<ContentPage
    ...
    BackgroundImageSource="GradientBackground.png">
```

Does anyone know how to fix or a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: What is the image dimension for Tablet?

Comment: I am currently trying to resize it.  But I am suffering from another error when I do...  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file  '/Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.Mobile.iOS/9680b637e2cb8a8a2e2c4e64a133d0c0/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/optimized/GradientBackground.png'

Comment: Make file as Copy if Newer using property window. I think file is not copied.

Comment: Instead of setting contentpage background image, put a outer Grid to existing control and put image there. And set Aspect="AspectFill"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am suffering from another error when I do...
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file...

Try to clean/rebuild your project. And then re-add the image.

If you put the image in the Xamarin.forms project as [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images), image needs to be set to `Build Action: EmbeddedResource`.

Have a try to set backgroundImage by yourself if you problem still exist by using `BackgroundImageSource`:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>

            <Image Source="BackGroundImage.jpg" 
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   />

            <!-- Place your layouts and controls here, for example-->

        </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks.  I had tried something similar before but for some other reason it did not work.  Incidentally, the issue with the image not being found was fixed by, opening the image in VS, clicking properties and setting to 32bpp (that field had become blank??)